# Можно ли восстановить загрузочный сектор Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, восстановление

Вопрос. Можно ли восстановить загрузочный сектор... windows?
ну, или накатить новый так сказать..

Если у HDD битые сектора.

Comment: Если у HDD битые сектора, нужно в первую очередь покупать другой HDD

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов:
1) https://habr.com/ru/post/117661/
2) https://www.starusrecovery.ru/articles/how-to-recover-master-boot-record.html
3) Восстановление через установщик

Comment: @andreymal, капитан очевидность перелогиньтесь. вопрос стоит по другому.